# Search for specific value in a deep nested JsonArray/JsonObject

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a deep nested JsonObject like this, what is the best way to search for a specific value (null in this example) in this object?

```
{
  "monitors" : ["monitor1"],
  "index" : [{
    "patterns" : [ "*" ],
    "masked" : [ "abcd", "*ip_dest*::/[0-9]{1,3}$/::XXX"],
    "allowed" : [ "123", null ]
  }],
  "permissions" : [ ]
}
```

For this example, I have a list of keys, I want to get the values for those keys, check if the value has `Array` type and if yes, search if there is any `null` in that array. Here is the code I have:

```
for (Entry<String, DataType> allowedKey : allowedKeys.entrySet()) {
            DataType dataType = allowedKey.getValue();
            JsonNode value = contentAsNode.get(allowedKey.getKey());
            if (dataType == DataType.ARRAY && value != null) {
                try {
                      List contentArray = DefaultObjectMapper.objectMapper.convertValue(value, java.util.List.class);
                      if (contentArray.contains(null)) {
                          this.errorType = ErrorType.NULL_ARRAY_ELEMENT;
                          return false;
                      }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        this.errorType = ErrorType.BODY_NOT_PARSEABLE;
                        return false;
                 }
           }
    }
```

However `contains()` can not find `null` in this case, because I have a nested array. Since the structure of the Json object could be different each time (it could have nested array or maps or just an array), I was wondering what is the best way to parse a deep nested JsonObject to find a specific value?

More clarification: in the above example Json, the key that I am interested in is `index`, the value of this key, is a map (but it could be an array or nested array as well, we do not know beforehand), I want to check if there is any `null` in `index` values(which in this case, there is a null)

Comment: which value u want to extract if the  "allowed" array contains null ?

Comment: I need `if` statement to return `True` if there is any `null` in the values of that key.

Comment: Can you use any third party jar like Jsonpath ? it will provide u a flexible use.

Comment: Probably not, I was wondering if there is any way to use `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` directly as they are both available to me.

Comment: oh okay , Though have posted it , let me know if u cant use it I can change it

Answer (score 0):

One viable easy solution using JSONPath

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\r\n" + 
            "  \"monitors\" : [\"monitor1\"],\r\n" + 
            "  \"index\" : [{\r\n" + 
            "    \"patterns\" : [ \"*\" ],\r\n" + 
            "    \"masked\" : [ \"abcd\", \"*ip_dest*::/[0-9]{1,3}$/::XXX\"],\r\n" + 
            "    \"allowed\" : [ \"123\", null ]\r\n" + 
            "  }],\r\n" + 
            "  \"permissions\" : [ ]\r\n" + 
            "}" ;
    
    String path = "$.index[?(null in @.allowed)]"; //Check if allowed List has null value i.e. index->allowed
    DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(json);
    List<?> list = jsonContext.read(path);
    if(list.isEmpty()) { //Based on empty List u can return true or false
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Found");
    }       
}
```

**As per OP requirement psoting another solution iterate over JsonObject recursively**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\r\n" + 
            "  \"monitors\" : [\"monitor1\"],\r\n" + 
            "  \"index\" : [{\r\n" + 
            "    \"patterns\" : [ \"*\" ],\r\n" + 
            "    \"masked\" : [ \"abcd\", \"*ip_dest*::/[0-9]{1,3}$/::XXX\"],\r\n" + 
            "    \"allowed\" : [ \"123\", null ],\r\n" + 
            "    \"country\" : \"India\"\r\n" + 
            "  }],\r\n" + 
            "  \"permissions\" : [ ]\r\n" + 
            "}" ;
    try {
        iterateJson(new JSONObject(json));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public static void iterateJson(JSONObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        if(jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                if(jsonArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    iterateJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
                }else if(jsonArray.get(i) instanceof String){
                    List<String> list = mapper.readValue(jsonArray.toString(), new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
                    System.out.println(key+" :: "+list);
                    System.out.println("Contains null :: "+list.contains(null));
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else if(jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            iterateJson(jsonObject.getJSONObject(key));
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
masked :: [abcd, *ip_dest*::/[0-9]{1,3}$/::XXX]
Contains null :: false

allowed :: [123, null]
Contains null :: true

patterns :: [*]
Contains null :: false

monitors :: [monitor1]
Contains null :: false
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, unfortunately I can not use `JsonPath`, is there any way to use `JsonObject` or `JsonArray`? Can we flatten them so it can find `null` in nested structures as well?

Comment: Posted another solution see if thats works for u , it checks if index is of type JsonArray and "allowed" is also of type jsonArray and then it has a null value in it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Is there any way to convert `List contentArray = DefaultObjectMapper.objectMapper.convertValue(value, java.util.List.class);` to an `JSONArray`? I tried this: JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(contentArray)`, but it gives me an error.

Comment: whats ur contentArray ?

Comment: @user1080814 if I undesrstood correctly , check the update , Have used ObjectMapper to conevrt allowed values into List<String>

Comment: It is a `List`, values of a specific key in `JsonNode`

Comment: So any of the list can contains null and u have to find that key?

Comment: No i do not need to find the key, I just need to know if there is any `null` in the values of `index` key. The problem with your code is that you are specifically looking for values of `allowed`, however as I mentioned in my question, the structure of the Json could be different each time and so there might be no `allowed` key at all, what we know exists for sure is `index` key, that's it. and we want to check if there is any `null` in its values or not. The type of its values are different each time, they could be nested lists, nested maps or single list or single map.

Comment: okay , i tried to write the similar thing added one more key country under index not of jsonArray type , it will print only array inside index json

Comment: what is the library for `JSONObject`? is it `net.minidev.json.JSONObject` or  `org.json.JSONObject`? If the second one is correct, I do not have access to it, so I can not call `optJSONArray` as well. Also from your code, I think it only works if we have a map type as a value in the json string, right? I does not work if we have a list or nested list.

Comment: I have used org.json.JSONObject optJSONArray is a method in it see javadoc https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray-java.lang.String- , for ur need i have iteratively  recurse it , this works to verify null value in any of the json given irrespective of its structure (valid json)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233855/discussion-between-hades-and-user1080814).